# Same dataset with different yAxes in Chart.js Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a chart.js bar chart with two datasets called "orange" and "grey". Each has six values: "a", "b", "c", "d" and "f", resulting  in the [current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqnJe.png)

As you can see it is not easily readable. What I want is to have "b" in a different yAxes than the rest of the datapoints, but as far as I read, having different axes is only possible for datasets ("orange" and "grey" in my case).

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/gonzam/pen/dQOwJR)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var barChartData = {
  datasets: [{
    backgroundColor: "#fe8359",
    borderColor: "#fe8359",
    data: [3000, 3500006, 90000, 12, 80000, 7000],
    label: "orange"
  },{
    backgroundColor: "#e9e9e9",
    borderColor: "#e9e9e9",
    data: [5000, 2500000, 80000, 5, 90000, 9000],
    label: "grey"
  }],
  labels: ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
};



var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          id: 'A',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'left',
        },{
          display: true,
          id: 'B',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'right',
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
          },
        }]
      }
    }
});
```

How could I configure the chart to properly show this data, or how could I accommodate data to show up properly?